# Step counter in android (counter sensor doesn't work)

Tags: android

I try to make a basic pedometer app in android. But when I am getting below error

> Counter sensor not available

Please help me.

```
package com.starboardland.pedometer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CounterActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private TextView count;
    boolean activityRunning;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        count = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.count);

        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        activityRunning = true;
        Sensor countSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
        if (countSensor != null) {
            sensorManager.registerListener(this, countSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Count sensor not available!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        activityRunning = false;
        // if you unregister the last listener, the hardware will stop detecting step events
//        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (activityRunning) {
            count.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[0]));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to read about [why 'Can somebody help me?' is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541).

Answer (score 2):

The [Android 4.4 API Documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/about/versions/android-4.4.html#UserInput) states that the sensors are hardware dependent.

> Both step sensors are hardware dependent (Nexus 5 is the first device to support them), so you should check for availability with hasSystemFeature(), using the FEATURE_SENSOR_STEP_DETECTOR and FEATURE_SENSOR_STEP_COUNTER constants.

You should check if the device has the functionality first.

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_STEP_COUNTER)) {
    // the awesome stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not asking for permissions.
You need to add it on the manifest...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>
```

And get permissions...

```
    // GET PERMISSION
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
        // Ask for permission
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION}, 19);
    }
```