# Android Google Fit real time step counting

Tags: android, google-fit

I tried to count steps in real time using Google Fit SDK.

I used Sensor API to get step count changes in real time and it worked fine if I have Google Fit app installed on my phone.

But when I uninstalled Google Fit app, it didn't worked.

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong and what should I do?

Thanks

Comment: have you try something like this: https://github.com/theelfismike/android-step-counter/blob/master/src/com/starboardland/pedometer/CounterActivity.java

Comment: It's not working... It logs "Count sensor not available!"

Answer (score 1):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34460927/6176003), hope it helps you

The [Android 4.4 API Documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/en/about/versions/android-4.4.html#UserInput) states that the sensors are hardware dependent.

> Both step sensors are hardware dependent (Nexus 5 is the first device to support them), so you should check for availability with hasSystemFeature(), using the FEATURE_SENSOR_STEP_DETECTOR and FEATURE_SENSOR_STEP_COUNTER constants.

You should check if the device has the functionality first.

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_SENSOR_STEP_COUNTER)) {
    // the awesome stuff here
}
```

Comment: What if the device doesn't support step sensors?

Comment: if device doesnt have support step sensor you couldn't do much. But some devices simply refused that (full wake-up) functionality because of power consumption. Check this link and focus on github listener should help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30891866/6176003